# Print paragraph neatly on another file

Tags: java, file

I am working on a java program to print a paragraph neatly. However, as it is now, the program prints the output on console like so:

```
private static void printSolution(String[] words, int[] print, int n,int width) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        printSolution(words, print, print[n] - 1, width);
        int index = print[n];
        System.out.printf("%s", words[index]);
        width -= words[index].length();
        ++index;
        for (; index <= n; index++) {
            System.out.printf(" %s", words[index]);
            width -= words[index].length() + 1;
        }

        while (width > 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            width--;
        }

        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
```

Now, I want to change it a little bit and print the output to another file (output.txt), but I am not that familiar Java so I need help with this. So what I don't know how to do is store the result in a String and format it the way printf does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.format() to do String formatting

So for instance this line:

```
System.out.printf("%s", words[index]);
```

Can be done like this:

```
String newStr = String.format("%s", words[index]);
```

And then you can append the rest of your lines to newStr. If you want to write the newString to a file use BufferedWriter.

Also your code call throws a Stackoverflow exception here

```
printSolution(words, print, print[n] - 1, width);
```